# How to store per thread contextual data in c#?

Tags: c#, thread-local

My concrete need is to store remote IP so it can be printed while logging, without explicitly passing it down every method call. A sort of per thread environment variable scope.

I thought of having a per thread Singleton so logger can access it. Is there a better/safer way?

Make it work with async is a plus.

My ideal API should look like this:

```
using (new LogScope("key1", "value1"))
{
   Call1();
}

using (new LogScope("key1", "value1"))
{
    Call1();
}

void Call1()
{
    using (new LogScope("key2", "value2"))
    {
        Call2();     // key1:value1 key2:value2
        using (new LogScope("key1", "value3"))
        {
            Call2(); // key1:value3 key2:value2
        }
    }
    using (new LogScope("key1", "value3"))
    {
        Call2();     // key1:value3
    }
}

void Call2()
{
    foreach (var kv in LogScope.Context) Console.Write("'{0}':'{1}' ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see in your `foreach` loop?  Only the inner `LogScope`'s values (`key2` only), or both `LogScope`s combined (`key1` + `key2`).  And if it's combined, what is the purpose of the `LogScope` instance.  What gets disposed when you exit the `using` block?

Comment: Clarified my question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I think I grasp your intent, but there is still one case that is not completely covered: When you exit a `using` block.  Do you expect the key/values to revert to whatever they were before the scope was entered?  I assume yes, but I want to make sure.  And your sample doesn't quite cover that case.

Comment: Yep. I expect scope to override only while in-scope.

Comment: Then you can have a look at my answer.  It should work exactly as your describe.

Answer (score 1):

a) If you would like to use a per thread singleton, you definitely should not write your own, there are out of the box solutions. Mainly all modern DI framework supports instantiate option like singletons, and singletons per thread.  Just an example from Ninject:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof (IAnyThing)).To(typeof (AnyThing)).InThreadScope();
```

or if you would not like to use / implement interface:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof (AnyThing)).To(typeof (AnyThing)).InThreadScope();
```

After that binding whereever you ask for your DI container an instance of AnyThing you got a per thread singleton. AnyThing could be really anything: say a POCO.

**EDIT:**
In case you would like any *custom* scoping, then just implement your scope definition, leave the rest of the container [look for Custom in this page](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)

b) You could use `ThreadLocal<T>`.

**EDIT:**
Before suggesting ThreadLocal one note about async expectation you mentioned in your question. Yes, ThreadLocal is not "compatible" with async.

However this is not the root of the problem: *Thread affinity* is not "compatible" with most of the concurrent programming design patterns (CDP), because many CDP uses the concept of *thread "unaffinity"*, like pool, serializing to a message queue, marshaling to other thread etc. So having a thread affinity as an expectation, and having async work as an expectation seems to be not a good idea together, one should be dropped or replaced. Note this is not about the async keyword, this is about the async controlflow.
**END EDIT**

Please refer to [sample code in msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    // Demonstrates: 
    //      ThreadLocal(T) constructor 
    //      ThreadLocal(T).Value 
    //      One usage of ThreadLocal(T) 
    static void Main()
    {
        // Thread-Local variable that yields a name for a thread
        ThreadLocal<string> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
        {
            return "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        });

        // Action that prints out ThreadName for the current thread
        Action action = () =>
        {
            // If ThreadName.IsValueCreated is true, it means that we are not the 
            // first action to run on this thread. 
            bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated;

            Console.WriteLine("ThreadName = {0} {1}", ThreadName.Value, repeat ? "(repeat)" : "");
        };

        // Launch eight of them.  On 4 cores or less, you should see some repeat ThreadNames
        Parallel.Invoke(action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action);

        // Dispose when you are done
        ThreadName.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: ThreadLocal does not work with async. It seems I need CallContext.LogicalGetData() and CallContext.LogicalSetData() but it requires carrying "name" parameter around.

Comment: Gatis, you are right, please see my edits in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most optimal implementation. But it should do what you are looking for.  And it should at least demonstrate some principles you can reuse.

```
public class LogScope : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<Stack<Dictionary<string, string>>> currentDictionary =
        new ThreadLocal<Stack<Dictionary<string, string>>>(() => new Stack<Dictionary<string, string>>());

    public LogScope(string key, string value)
    {
        var stack = currentDictionary.Value;
        Dictionary<string, string> newDictionary = null;
        if (stack.Count == 0)
        {
            newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        else
        {
            newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(stack.Peek());
        }

        newDictionary[key] = value;

        stack.Push(newDictionary);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        currentDictionary.Value.Pop();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Context
    {
        get
        {
            var stack = currentDictionary.Value;
            if (stack.Count == 0)
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            }
            else
            {
                return stack.Peek();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I should specify that in my implementation of `LogScope`, an instance of `LogScope` will only work properly if it is instantiated and disposed on the same thread.  If you create a `LogScope` in one thread, and then dispose it in another thread, then the results are undefined.  Likewise, while a `LogScope` instance is in effect, its key/values will only be visible within that thread.

Comment: I came up with a similar implementation. Will currentDictionary get disposed when Thread finishes?

Comment: It will get disposed eventually. When the thread finishes, there are no more references to that thread-specific stack, so it becomes subject to garbage collection as would be expected.

Comment: For any custom defined scope: A DI container should provide out of the box   singleton instance for it. For example Ninject: (see for Custom) https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes